# Gitlens hangs when fetching remote repository via WSL

Tags: wsl-2, gitlens

I'm using Gitlens with VS Code via Git installed in WSL2. (I'm using Amazon Linux 2 as my distro). Performing a fetch in either the Remotes or Repositories view in Gitlens causes it to hang. It puts up a "Fetching" notification but never completes. Doing a fetch in command line Git works no problem.

There's a reported issue: https://github.com/eamodio/vscode-gitlens/issues/1497 but no resolution. I'm wondering if anyone can suggest how to debug this or anything else I could try. Love the look of Gitlens but obviously it's unusable in this state.

Versions:
Windows 10 Home 10.0.19042 Build 19042,
Visual Studio Code 1.59.1 (July 2021),
Gitlens v11.6.0 installed under WSL.

Comment: did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @senecaTheMeek, yes, see the answer I've added.

Answer (score 2):

This problem went away for me. I believe it was a git credentials problem. I used `git config credential.helper store` to store my git credentials.At the same time I also moved to running inside a WSL container but I don't think that was material to the problem.

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem by switching to SSH key authentication. I had to clone the repository again via the SSH link and then it worked fine.